# Tensorflow new Op CUDA kernel memory management

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am have implemented a rather complex new Op in Tensorflow with a GPU CUDA kernel.
This Op requires a lot of dynamic memory allocation of variables which are not tensors and are deallocated after the op is done, more specifically it involves using a hash table.

Right now I am using `cudaMalloc()` and `cudaFree()` but I have noticed Tensorflow has its own type called `Eigen::GPUDevice` which has the ability to allocate and deallocate memory on the GPU.

My questions:

1. Is it best practice to use `Eigen::GPUDevice` to manage GPU memory;
2. By using `Eigen::GPUDevice` instead of the CUDA API I am "automatically" enabling multi-GPU support since different `GPUDevices` can be passed to the Op;
3. Should I extend this idea to the CPU kernel and see if there is a `CPUDevice` type which also manages the memory instead of using C++ syntax (i.e. `auto var = new int[100]; delete[] var`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The is no direct public guideline for this issue. I usually just let the TensorFlow allocate this information by

```cpp
template<typename Device, typename Dtype>
class MyOp: public OpKernel {
{
public:
  explicit MyOp(OpKernelConstruction *context) :
      OpKernel(context)
  {
    // ...
  }

  void Compute(OpKernelContext *context) override
  {
    Tensor* tmp_var = nullptr;
    Tensor* output = nullptr;

    TensorShape some_shape, some_shape2;

    // temparily use this space
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(ctx, ctx->allocate_temp(DT_FLOAT, some_shape, &tmp_var));
    // allocate memory for output tensor
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(ctx, ctx->allocate_output(0, some_shape2, &output));
```

1. whatever needs memory, should be allocated by the TensorFlow context and not by custom `cudaMalloc` or `new type[num]` calls.
2. the context should provide the information for the Allocator
3. see below

Consider, for the sake of simplicity just adding two matrices ([full example](https://github.com/cgtuebingen/tf_custom_op)).
TensorFlow-Operations usually contain the following structure:

**Op description** having `REGISTER_OP`, which is responsible for shape-checking, and setting the output shape ([example](https://github.com/cgtuebingen/tf_custom_op/blob/master/matrix_add/ops/matrix_add.cc))

**OpKernel** responsible for allocating memory, getting pointer to the inputs and setup stuff, (see above or [this](https://github.com/cgtuebingen/tf_custom_op/blob/master/matrix_add/kernels/matrix_add_op.cc) )

**Functor** for the implementation itself, like

```cpp
Tensor* output = nullptr;
Tensor* tmp_var = nullptr;
OP_REQUIRES_OK(ctx, ctx->allocate_output(0, output_shape, &output));
OP_REQUIRES_OK(ctx, ctx->allocate_temp(0, some_shape, &tmp_var));
// the function does not need to care about the memory allocation as everything is already setup at this point
::tensorflow::functor::MyFunctor<Device, Dtype>()(ctx, inputA, inputB, tmp_var, output);
```

You are just left by implementing

```cpp
    // gpu version
    template <typename Dtype>
    struct MyFunctor<GPUDevice, Dtype> {
      void operator ()(::tensorflow::OpKernelContext* ctx,...)

    // cpu version
    template <typename Dtype>
    struct MyFunctor<CPUDevice, Dtype> {
      void operator ()(::tensorflow::OpKernelContext* ctx,...)
```

**edit**

- allocate_persistent: use this if you need your data between Op invocations like one-time index structures.[[example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4be569ca656b6f46efb73bd3aaa87c6ad42dd37d/tensorflow/core/kernels/count_up_to_op.cc#L89)]
- allocate_temp just tmp memory which will be not retained at the end of the `Compute` method lifetime. [[example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/982549ea3423df4270ff154e5c764beb43d472da/tensorflow/core/kernels/histogram_op_gpu.cu.cc#L49)]

But I highly recommend reading the comment in the [source-code here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/584876113e6248639d18d4e16c77b47cb1b251c1/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L753-L801) and then decided depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all the examples. Can you comment on why you use `allocate_temp()` instead of `allocate_persistent() `as suggested by mrry's answer?

Comment: It depends on your use case and if you are willing to free memory. See the [comments in the TensorFlow repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/584876113e6248639d18d4e16c77b47cb1b251c1/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L753-L801). I suggest to use `allocate_output` in the kernel if the Op is stateless (which most Ops are). GPU memory is a rare resource (for most people), so I usually free my stuff.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I have some followup questions that you might be able to help with. 1. How do you go about allocating a user defined C++ types in this manner? For example an array of structs. 2. How about static memory e.g. `int a[3] = {1,2,3}`, should I be concerned about this?

Comment: I do not allocate structs this way. But I would probably serialize the stuff into byte-arrays. The last example is placed on the stack, so there should be usually no problems.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to use the [`OpKernelContext::allocate_persistent()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bd0d204700df1a1a245b0593a11efd8ede139311/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L257) method to allocate memory, in the form of a `tensorflow::Tensor`, that outlives a single call to `OpKernel::Compute()`. It uses the appropriate [`Allocator*`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bd0d204700df1a1a245b0593a11efd8ede139311/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h#L68) for the device, so if the kernel runs on a GPU device, it will allocate GPU memory for that particular device, and if it runs on a CPU device it will allocate CPU memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Perhaps I am over-reaching, but can you give a brief comment on static memory allocation (compile time)? For example, declaration of static shape arrays inside CUDA kernels, will this cause issues in a multi-GPU scenario?