# Allocating C++/CUDA memory within TensorFlow Op

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

This question is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580580/tensorflow-new-op-cuda-kernel-memory-managment) where I asked how to allocate GPU or CPU memory in a TensorFlow Op.

I wish to be able to allocate memory for any C++ type in GPU/CPU in a TensorFlow Op. Using `context` one can allocate new tensors (in CPU or GPU) and if they are of a "regular" C++ type one can get a C++ pointer. Example:

```
    Tensor tensor;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_temp(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({n_elements}), &tensor));
    float * ptr = tensor.flat<float>().data();
```

My problem is when trying to allocate user-defined types for instance:

```
struct A{
    float a;
    int b;
};
```

Then there is no correspondent Tensorflow type to allocate as. I know that in this case, I could just allocate a `float` tensor and an `int` tensor, but for more complex data-structures this makes the code quite messy.

I tried to work around it by allocating bytes (`DT_UINT8`) and using `reinterpret_cast` to cast to the desired pointer type (as one of the comments from an answer in my previous question suggested). Here is my implementation:

```
template<typename t> void allocate(void ** ptr_address, int num_elements){
    Tensor tensor;
    int number_of_bytes = num_elements * sizeof(t);
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_temp(DT_UINT8, TensorShape({number_of_bytes}), &tensor));
    *ptr_address = reinterpret_cast<t*>(tensor.flat<unsigned char>().data());
}
```

In theory, I would be able to use `A* a; allocate<A>(&a, 5);` for the class defined above instead of auto `a = new A[5];` or `cudaMalloc((void**)&a, 5*sizeof(A))`.

The problem is that after the Op runs it freezes and TensorFlow does not return to python (I have made sure it runs through `printf` debugging). I am sure it is because of this method of allocation because when I use regular C++/CUDA allocation I don't have this problem.

Is there something wrong with this method of allocation or is something else the issue?

Comment: Are you sure the "Tensor tensor" will survive. This looks like being only function scope. I would try `allocate(void ** ptr_address, int num_elements, Tensor **tensor)`

Comment: Thanks again, I will try that. I know that `Tensor tensor` does not survive but I thought it shouldn't matter since the memory would remain allocated until the end of Compute.

Comment: cross-ref to issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17064